# CKEditor output in BBcode format not HTML

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor in a form. When I submit that form the content of I wrote in the text area of the CKEditor is saved in database in such format `[b]helllo[/b][size=100]fefdf[/size]:*)`. In another page when I retrieve the data it shows in HTML as same `[b]helllo[/b][size=100]fefdf[/size]:*)` instead of the output in BBCode format. Can anyone help me with how to get it in BBcode format?

**What I want:**

[image: What I want]

**What I am getting:**

[image: What I am getting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello thanks for the help i solved the problem just removed the line "extraPlugins : 'bbcode'," and now its working

Answer (score 1):

I deduce that BBCode option is activated when you call the editor (see [this example code](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7346/_samples/bbcode.html)), so that shouldn't be the issue.

One thing you could try is setting the [**basicEntities**](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.basicEntities) config to *false*.

Taken from the [CKeditor API](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.customConfig):

`<static> {Boolean} CKEDITOR.config.basicEntities` `Since: 3.0`

> Whether to escape basic HTML entities in the document, including:
>
> - nbsp
> - gt
> - lt
> - amp
>
> Note: It should not be subject to change **unless when outputting a non-HTML data format like BBCode**.
>
> Defined in: plugins/entities/plugin.js.

```
config.basicEntities = false;

Default Value:

true
```

Comment: soory but this is not the answer to my question friend . i want to display the ckeditor data value stored in my database which is "[b]helllo[/b][size=100]fefdf[/size]:*)" in proper format such that of the mention above WHAT I WANT. CAN U HELP ME OUT

Comment: I UNDERSTOOD THAT. AND PLEASE DON'T USE CAPITAL LETTERS / DON'T SHOUT AT ME.

Comment: Going to the question...if you look at the first link I posted, you'll see that **it should** work as you want. If it doesn't, it means something is interfering, and that's likely to be html encoding that prevents CKeditor from correctly rendering the BBCode. Are you running something like htmlentities() or other encoding function?

Comment: so sorry i was'nt shouting friend . thanks for helping me out . i was just pointing the bbcode image above . no m not running htmlentities() dnt knw why its not showing, m tensed